# Couchdb maven dependency not importing /resolving Session and document

Tags: java, spring, maven, maven-2, couchdb

i was trying to understand couchDB by following this example :-

**http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/couchdb-relax.html**

all the couch db maven dependencies i have imported (which i have found on google )they **do not resolve Session** and **document**

```
import com.fourspaces.couchdb.Session;
import com.fourspaces.couchdb.Document;
```

i can always get it run using jar locally as i learned it here:
[How to add local jar files in maven project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-in-maven-project)

but then i have to manually copy jar(s) in my other environments (production/Testing...) .

I was wondering is there any work around for this ?

Please give me some hints or suggestions.

Thanks.

***UPDATED***

Manually adding the jar in system and pointing it to the directory as following:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>apache-collections-commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.apache-collections-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/couchdbJars/apache-collections-commons-collections-3.1.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/couchdbJars/commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/couchdbJars/commons-codec-1.6.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient-3.1</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.commons-httpclient-3.1</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/couchdbJars/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang-2.6</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.commons-lang-2.6</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/couchdbJars/commons-lang-2.6.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging-api-1.1.1</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.commons-logging-api-1.1.1</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/couchdbJars/commons-logging-api-1.1.1.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>couchdb</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.couchdb</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/couchdbJars/couchdb4j-0.1.2.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ezmorph-1.0.6.jar</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ezmorph-1.0.6.jar</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/couchdbJars/ezmorph-1.0.6.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>httpclient-4.2.1</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.httpclient-4.2.1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/couchdbJars/httpclient-4.2.1.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>httpcore-4.2.1</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.httpcore-4.2.1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/couchdbJars/httpcore-4.2.1.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>json.lib</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.jsonLib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/couchdbJars/json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>json-simple-1.1</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.json-simple-1.1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/couchdbJars/json-simple-1.1.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: i m facing the same problem please help me out

Comment: @Vartika you can solve it by manually defining it in pom. Let me know if you need code , i can update.

Comment: Sir, I added it manually only like adding the groupid, artifact id then its version. But its showing error of missing artifact fro couchdb4j

Comment: If you can update the code please update it.

Comment: @Vartika see my answer then